# Emacs Adding Preprocessor to Major Mode

Tags: regex, emacs, syntax, preprocessor, major-mode

I am trying to modify the fortran major mode to work with a preprocessor a colleague wrote.  The preprocessor directives are all prefixed by a "."

for example:

```
.set

.macro
```

function similar to C's `#define`

This far, I have:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'fortran-mode
 '(("\\<\\(set\\|macro\\|endmacro\\)\\>" . font-lock-preprocessor-face)))
```

Unfortunately, This does not highlight the "." which is desirable.  Also, the pattern should only match if it appears at the start of the line.
I've tried:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'fortran-mode
 '(("\\<\\(^\.set\\|^\.macro\\|^\.endmacro\\)\\>" . font-lock-preprocessor-face)))
```

but that didn't work.

Any help on how to make this regex match would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: `"^\\s-*\\.\\(set\\|macro\\|endmacro\\)\\>"`

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm.  I had actually wanted to only change the syntax highlighting if the '.' was in the first column.  To accomplish that, I just removed the "\\s-*".  (It's a very basic pre-processor).

Comment: @mgilson - yeah, wasn't sure if you wanted to allow leading whitespace, figured it wouldn't hurt either way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `\\.` rather that `^\.`. The double slashed escapes the special meaning of backslashes, creating the string `\.`, whereas the `^` in the latter has no special meaning.

Comment: Ah, now I see, `\\<` match the beginning of a word and `\\.` match a period, they can never match at the same time (unless you do something weire with the syntax table entry for `.`).